# Island-hopping, gigantic-sized predator?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, evolution, island

I wish to create the necessary/sufficient conditions for an island-hopping super predator. Relevant characteristics below:

- In terms of size, it is to be massive, perhaps akin to a
  Tyrannosaurus while everything else (its prey) is 1/10 the size at most (but mostly much smaller).
- Its biome is the archipelago.
- It is amphibious.
- Its diet is only land animals.
- One of this animal per archipelago (unless it gets challenged, which
  results in a fight to the death). It ventures into the deep sea only
  to mate.
- Instead of residing on any one island permanently, it will be a
  nomadic predator: at times resting on one island and at times resting
  in the nearby sea.
- While some islands are largish, the majority of islands in the archipelago are very small. It would be likely that once the predator birthed from the sea, it would be visible across the entire island.

This is how I envision the species and its niche. Though there are no Earth analogs of this kind of animal, I don't believe I have trespassed against any known laws of biology or physics. However, it wouldn't be the first time I was wrong about that!

Archipelago for reference. Imagine a world with clusters of this arrangement:

[image]

### Question

Based on the existing scholarship, what grievances, if any, would evolutionary/biological science have with the desired characteristics of this species? And optionally, how might I redress them?

Comment: Any creature capable of swimming well enough to make a trek to the deep ocean to mate will certainly eat anything and everything it can catch in the water as well as on land.  It might prefer hunting land animals since they can't swim as well and are easily drowned, but it's hardly going to pass up aquatic food sources without a good reason.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt the small islands will have enough biomass to sustain such a big animal.

Island dwarfism is an adaptation to the limited resources available on islands and archipelagos. Your creature seems to go in the opposite directions, and the fact that it feeds only on land creatures doesn't help.

Comment: *"I doubt the small islands will have enough biomass to sustain such a big animal."* .. of course individual small islands won't but the OP has obviously already considered and allowed for that by making it 'nomadic' with a very large range and personal territory  encompassing a great many small islands .. clearly it is supposed to deplete one island then move on only returning to that island after it has repopulated .. how do the islands repopulate / what are the prey animals is a worthwhile question perhaps.

Comment: I thought as many steps ahead as I could, bit of a delicate balancing act though. Related: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/233677/make-a-tiny-island-robust-to-ecologic-collapse?rq=1

Comment: @ArashHowaida so you have people who visit and re-establish animals for their own purposes? Solves the problem of how long it takes wiped out species to find their way back to the is!and & repopulate it.

Comment: @Pelinore Oh, not the same world, but similar challenge they grapple with. Interesting thought though

Answer (score 4):

It's called a saltwater crocodile.  The normal ones are already terrifying.

[This 4 metric ton beast existed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcosuchus#:%7E:text=Sarcosuchus%20was%20a%20giant%20relative,the%20length%20of%20the%20skull.)  You're not taking very many liberties with biology.